# Order entered via Admin not showing in Customer Login Account - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

When we create an order for a customer via the admin console the order is not visible by the customer when they login to their account to check the order.

Comment: Could you find it in tables: `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid`?

Comment: Yes they are in both tables.

Comment: Did you check the email for order? Does it match with customer account?

Comment: Yes. We created the order using the customer account created by the customer.